# Groovy string parsing by ignoring "$" or any character(ps: no control over input data)

Tags: java, string, groovy, char, groovyscriptengine

I am trying to replace a particular word say `password` to `*******` from a string which has characters such as `$` and `\n` in Groovy.

I cannot escape them by using `\` because i have no control over data i receive and even in the final output i need as it was earlier with `$`.

i tried `str.replaceAll("password","**")`

gives:

> illegal string body character after dollar sign;
>     solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 2, column 8.
>     afdmas$

```
def str="""hello how  
you$
password
doing"""
```

expected o/p :

```
hello how  
you$
**
doing
```

Comment: You can try to use an instance of a `String` with `''` instead of `GString` which is quoted with `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you don't have access to the input data because you use string literal in the example and the error you get is from this example as well. In this case you can use Groovy [single-quoted](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_single_quoted_string) strings but they are without [interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation). Or if interpolation is necessary then you can use [slashy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_slashy_string) or [dollar slashy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_dollar_slashy_string) strings which additionally don't require backslash escaping:

```
def str='''"hello how
you$ password doing'''
```

```
def str=/"hello how
you$ password doing/
```

```
def str=$/"hello how
you$ password doing/$
```

*Formatting is the same as in OP